# Regex of a parapgraph starting with specefic text

Tags: regex

I would like to remove a paragraph starting with a specefic words from a text using regex.
Imagine we have lorem ipsum text and we want to remove the first paragraph ( http://en.lipsum.com/feed/html )

I am using python, I tried :

```
t = r"^Lorem ipsum.*\n\n"
text.replace(t,"")
```

Nothing happened to the text. My question is not about python , but about the regex expression matching a paragraph that starts with certain words .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This greatly depends on what is your definition of "paragraph" - is it a sequence of lines separated by a blank line? Most of the regexp-processing tools are line-oriented, they process text line by line, so they might not work as you would expect. This holds for Python `re` library as well, but it provides ways around that - in your case something like `re.sub('^Lorem ipsum.*?\n\n', '', text, flags=(re.S | re.M))` should do the job (note that `text.replace` does not work with regexp at all).

This works if the text is short enough, but for long texts you should use a bit different approach - I myself would use `awk`, others might suggest `perl`, `python` could be used too; simpler regexp-only tools like `grep` or `sed` are probably out of the game here.

Comment: The problem was `text.replace()` that doesn't work with regex .

Answer (score 0):

Your regex won't work if there are line breaks in your paragraph (it works only for a single line paragraph). Try the following regex: `^Lorem ipsum[\s\S]*\n\n`. see http://regex101.com/r/fF9uZ6

Comment: You should add a '?' for lazy match instead of greedy.